# The purpose of 'value' keyword in Oracle Select Statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, subquery

Whats is the difference between:

```
select 'mari makan'  value   from dual ;
```

and

```
select 'mari makan'  from dual ;
```

when querying from oracle table.

Precisely, what is the purpose of `value` keyword in above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first names the column `value`.  It is more typically written using `as`:

```
select 'mari makan' as value 
from dual ;
```

The second does not give a user-defined name to the column.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between them is that the first query aliasing this column, and giving it a unique name, while the other one doesn't.

What does that mean?

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 'asda' FROM dual
   UNION 
   SELECT 'asdasda' FROM dual
)
WHERE ??? = ??
```

This query is not aliasing the column, if you would want to use this column in the other query, you will have a problem. I think the default is to name the column after what you selected, which means it will be named 'asda' .

As opposed to:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT 'asda' Col1 FROM dual
   UNION 
   SELECT 'asdasda' as Col1 FROM dual
) WHERE Col1 <> 'asda'
```

Which will let you call this column from an outer query.

The standard is to write it as `SELECT <Col> AS <New_Name>` but it can be written with out the `AS` as well.